# How is the origin is a saddle point for $f(x, y) = x^2 −y^4$?

Tags: calculus

It is indeed a critical point since partial derivatives respect to $x$ and $y$ are zero at the origin.

And I found $f_{xx} = 2$, $f_{yy} = -12y^2$, $f_{xy} = 0$

From the Hessian thing $f_{xx}*f_{yy} - (f_{xy})^2 = 0$ so the test is inconclusive but the textbook says origin is a saddle point. I don't know what else I can do to determine behaviour of a critical point. Maybe I miss something very simple.

Comment: Prove that it is neither a local maximum (since $f(x,0)>f(0,0)$) nor a local minimum (since $f(0,y)<f(0,0)$).

Comment: Is it always true that a critical point is a saddle point if it is neither a local min nor local max?

Comment: Well, what is your definition of a saddle point? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point

Comment: @Moo I don't think it does.

Comment: @AnneBauval The point where the graph goes up in one direction and goes down in another direction I guess. I've never explicitly defined saddle point before.

Comment: @AnneBauval: What do you mean - it is the same approach as the posted answer?

Comment: @Moo I mean that the situation in the post you linked to is really much less simple than the post here, so I honestly doubt it helps.

Comment: @AtaberkYanardağ according to the Wikipedia page  linked above, you don't need it to be a min in one direction and a max in another one like in the answer below. You only need the point to be neither a local min nor a local max (which is proved in my first comment above).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When we move along the $x$-axis, we have
$$
f(x, 0) = x^2,
$$
which shows that $(0, 0)$ is a local minimum when the function is restricted on the $x$-axis.

On the other hand, when we move along the $y$-axis, we have
$$
f(0, y) = -y^4,
$$
which shows that $(0, 0)$ is a local maximum when the function is restricted on the $y$-axis.

Thus the origin is a saddle point (i.e., a critical point that is not a local extremum).

Comment: What about $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3$? Your approach (up until the last phrase) might be misleading.

Comment: If $f(x, y) = x^2 + y^3$, then by $f(0, y) = y^3$ we can conclude that $(0, 0)$ is not a local extremum (since it is not a local extremum on the $y$-axis).

Comment: Right. I just wanted to emphasize that you don’t need to see a local max in one direction and a local min in another.